# Basic question about python classes and variables from a new programmer

Tags: python

I have a simple question about variable values being updated, please. 
I ran the following code:

```
class Number:
    def __init__(self,val):
        self.val=val

    def addthistoobj(self,obj):
        obj.val=self.val+obj.val

    def addthistovar(self,var):
        var=self.val+var

x=Number(7)
print("value of x is",x.val)

y=Number(10)
print("value  of y (obj) is",y.val)
x.addthistoobj(y)
print("value  of y (obj) after adding is",y.val)

p=10
print("value  of p (var) is",p)
x.addthistovar(p)
print("value  of p (var) after adding is",p)
```

The output I got was:

"

value of x is 7

value  of y (obj) is 10

value  of y(obj) after adding is 17

value  of p (var) is 10

value  of p (var) after adding is 10

"

The value of the object gets updated but the value of the variable does not.

Why is this the case?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: You never update `p`, the variable. You create *a new variable* `var` that is local to the method and ceases to exist once the method terminates. In your other method, you *mutate an object*, so any reference to that object will reflect that change

Comment: I also suggest reading the following: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: Short answer: int type is **inmutable**, so when used as parameter, and you try to modify it, it creates a local scoped variable with the same name. You are not passing 
You can read about it here https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#how-do-i-write-a-function-with-output-parameters-call-by-reference
tldr: do not modify parameters, return new ones.

Answer (score 0):

When you do `x.addthistovar(p)`, you are adding the value of `x` to `p` and creating a new object called var, but it "dies off" as the scope of the `addthistovar` function closes.

If you wanted to have `p == 17` after that, you would need a return statement.

```
class Number:
    ...
    def addthistovar(self,var):
        return self.val + var
    ...

p = x.addthistovar(p)
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your function to return the sum. As the value you are passing is not related to that object, thus can't be saved unless you define a field for it. You can save the result in a variable `result` and use it to your `print` statment.

```
   class Number:
        def __init__(self,val):
            self.val=val

    def addthistoobj(self,obj):
        obj.val=self.val+obj.val

    def addthistovar(self,var):
        return self.val+var

x=Number(7)
print("value of x is",x.val)

y=Number(10)
print("value  of y (obj) is",y.val)
x.addthistoobj(y)
print("value  of y (obj) after adding is",y.val)

p=10
print("value  of p (var) is",p)
result = x.addthistovar(p)
print("value  of p (var) after adding is", result)
```

Comment: `p` refers to an object, just like `x` and `y`.

Answer (score 0):

This is because `p` never gets modified. Let's look at a more simple example:

```py
def add_to(x, y):
   x = x + y

a, b = 1, 2

add_to(a, b)
```

This might lead you to believe that `x` will be re-assigned during the call to `add_to`. That's not the case. `x` in the scope of `add_to` becomes a different object, because the `+` operator for ints returns a new int. It also gets garbage collected (disappears) at the end of the scope of `add_to`. To reassign `a`, you would first need to return the new value, and re-assign it:

```py
def add_to(x, y):
    return x + y # this returns a new integer created by x + y

a, b = 1, 2

a = add_to(a, b) # this reassigns the value 3 to a
```

Now for your class, you'd need to do the same thing:

```py
class Number:
    def __init__(self,val):
        self.val=val

    def addthistoobj(self,obj):
        obj.val=self.val+obj.val

    def addthistovar(self,var):
        return self.val+var

p = 10
x = Number(7)

p = x.addthistovar(p)

p
17
```